# How to get a list of all consumer queue rabbitMq?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

is there any simple/default way to get a list of all consumers by individual consumers in the application created by spring-boot and rabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the info using the HTTP API:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.8.16/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html

```
/api/consumers
```

```
/api/consumers/vhost
```

also in queue details